# Wallet won't close because there's too much money in it

Tags: comfort, efficiency

I know carrying around this much cash is not a good idea and it is better to use card instead but is there a hack to close a wallet full of cash so it could fit in my pockets?

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic

Comment: If this is off-topic here, where is it on topic?

Comment: *If you really have too much money, you can send the excess to me...*

Comment: I hate when I have too much money.

Comment: When I lived in Asia, we would have called this a "happy problem" :-)

Comment: Why not hire someone to carry your money around for you?

Answer (score 14):

As a former taxi driver, I used to have to carry a day's cash intake on my person, at least long enough to take it to the bank and deposit most of it.  I routinely found it more than I could close inside my wallet, especially after I switched to a tri-fold type.

My solution was to carry my cab fares and the day's starting wad (enough to change a $50 for a $5 fare, at least) in my shirt pocket (button-up collared shirt), inside a vest.  As I accumulated cash through the day, I'd transfer $20 and $50 bills from the shirt pocket to the inside vest pocket -- still accessible, but like the "drop" safe in a convenience store, somewhat protected in the event of a robbery (I was never robbed in two years driving, but it was always a possibility to consider), and hiding the bulk of the day's income even while making change.

Answer (score 12):

If you were to put cash in your wallet like in the picture you've provided, the thickness of cash in the fold of the wallet makes it difficult to close. Alternatively you could invest in a *money clip* these hold you cash tightly together, when folded in half you can fit a wad in either side of the wallet compartment. You could also use a paperclip, but if you have too much money in your wallet I'd buy a money clip :-)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This should not be a common situation,  as you really should only have a little more than enough money in your wallet for what you are going to need for the day. In other words, most of that money  should not be in there in the first place.

If you need to carry extra money one day, I would seriously consider alternate ways of carrying it for safety reasons and the following springs to mind:

- *A money belt* – Store the extra money around your waist in a belt, or dedicated  pouch for carrying money
- *A neck wallet* – When travelling some people use a wallet/bag to keep their passport and extra money safe. You hang this under your clothes around your neck
- *In your socks* – Another option could be to store some of the extra money tucked into your socks parallell to your legs (if your socks are long enough to keep them properly fastened)

Comment: Money belts are relatively secure, but rather difficult to get into if you need to access the cash inside.  They're better for carrying reserve when traveling than for daily spending.  Socks are a terrible place to keep money, and a neck wallet can lead to serious injury if someone tries to snatch it.

Comment: @ZeissIkon My main point is that this should be used for extra or reserve money, and as such they should be harder to reach.  You'll keep the wallet for the normal amount of money, and stash the extras somewhere else. This way you avoid the extremely thick wallet

Comment: Socks isn't a good idea. Was humour intended?

Comment: Socks **is** a good idea, mostly when living in a place with high crime numbers (although I agree with holroy, there's no actual reason to be carrying absurd amounts of cash)

Comment: Why should you only have enough money for the day?  That would mean you would have to waste time e.g. going to an ATM every day, or leave relatively large amounts of cash sitting around your home.  It also assumes that you are psychic, and so know just how much money you will need on any given day.

Comment: You don't need to be a psychic, you just have to know how to plan ahead @jamesqf it's called "budgeting"

Comment: @Just Do It: You never stop at a store on the way home, and find something you need on sale?  Or have a car breakdown?   Get invited for drinks/dinner, and need money for tips?  Get arrested and need bail?

Comment: 1. If I needed it it's already bought 2. Car breakdowns are unfortunate situations but I have insurance, so that's covered 3. You can always pay with a card and even tip with a card 4. Clean record @jamesqf

Comment: @Just Do It: You obviously arrange your life differently that I (and I think many people) do.  As said, I would find it quite boring myself, but different strokes...  As for the "clean record", that will last until you are unfortunate enough to run across a cop who doesn't like people of your age/race/sex/dress style, or who's just having a bad day.

Comment: I still don't see how being organized is boring, but hey if you like to run around carrying two thousand dollars in cash suit yourself I find that quite careless. And just cause a cop is having a day doesn't mean I'm automatically arrested, so that example was kind of pointless @jamesqf

Answer (score 1):

How about a large non-folding wallet? You could keep it your inside coat pocket, or wear cargo pants or shorts with a large pocket on the leg that this bigger wallet fits into.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the wallet to close with that much money inside, **use larger denomination bills.**  The point of having larger denomination bills is that it makes it easier to store, carry, and exchange larger amounts of money.  This has its downsides (see Larry Summers's post [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/02/16/its-time-to-kill-the-100-bill/), for example), but one of the advantages is that it solves the specific problem raised in this question.

Also consider leaving some in a safe or other such safe place where you can conveniently access it, if the banks are too inconvenient.  Carrying that much on your person concentrates your exposure to the risk of robbery.